# Installing Dynamics AX 4.0 SP2 on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, axapta

Is it possible to install AX 4.0 SP2 on SQL Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

This is officially supported for Dynamics AX 4.0

http://www.microsoft.com/dynamics/ax/using/40systemrequirements.mspx#EUEAC

This is link to the hotfix (KB944115) which enables SQL Server 2008 for AX 4.0 SP1 and SP2

[PartnerSource]
https://mbs.microsoft.com/knowledgebase/KBDisplay.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;893082